# Convert Oracle Standard Report output from text to excel

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I have a user requirement to convert oracle standard report (**Transaction Historical Summary**)'s output into Excel

I have tried to change output to xml to get the xml tags so to make rdf but it ends in error.

What are the steps to convert a standard report's output to excel?

Answer (score 0):

You'd use Report Builder's `DESFORMAT=SPREADSHEET` parameter; it works for Reports 10gR2 onwards.

Here's a tutorial which shows how to do that: "Building a Report for Spreadsheet Output" (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/bi.1012/b13895/orbr_paptoexcel.htm).

It doesn't make sense to copy/paste all those steps over here, so - have a look, follow the instructions.

---

If you're on lower version, you'd create a CSV (comma-separated-values) file (choose any delimiter you want, such as comma or semi-colon). Although it is not a XSL(X) file, Excel is capable of opening it *nicely*.

Comment: @Littefoot 
Thank you for your input, 
I know how to create reports, I am trying to convert an existing standard oracle report's output format

Comment: You're welcome. What is a "standard Oracle report"? Does it have to do anything with Oracle Apps. or E-Business Suite? If so, I'm sorry - I don't know anything about those reports ...

Comment: Thank you anyways.
It is an oracle inventory standard report

Comment: Right; I don't know those reports. I hope someone else will be able to assist.